# Tags for house swapping question

Tags: discussion, tagging

Please a suggestion for tags for [house swapping question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7186/is-a-contract-required-recommended-for-vacation-housing-swaps). Maybe creating some new ones?

Comment: I think [tag:accommodation] should be sufficient. The tag description already covers "special accommodation types".

Comment: I still hope that we can come up with one more tag that would include new(ish) stuff like house swapping or couch surfing. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

We have a tag [couchsurfing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/couchsurfing) with Usage guide:

> An online service and community (couchsurfing.com) based on hosts offering their couch to surfers (i.e. travellers) to use as a bed. Similar to Hospitality Club or GlobalFreeloaders.

Currently in use for 14 Open and 4 Closed Qs.

At present I can seem to find only two Qs about house swapping, the one mentioned in the Q here and [Home exchange sites?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4634/home-exchange-sites). Both from four years ago so we don't seem to have established a need for *tags for house swapping question*.

Hence IMO we should NOT be *creating some new ones* at this time for these purposes.